# Argument not being passed to function

Tags: powershell

I have created a PSObject and I want to pass the properties to another function which will then output the results, but it's not passing the property.

In the code below the `$VMHostObject.Name` is coming up blank in the `Enter-CellData` function but the data is there in the PSObject.

```
`Enter-CellData -WorkSheet $ws1 -CellRow $row -CellColumn $Column -Data $VMHostObject.Name`
```

`$VMHostObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            "Name" = $h.Name
            "ID" = $h.Id
            "HypervisiorName" = $view.Config.Product.Name
            "HypervisiorVersion" = $view.Config.Product.Version
            "HypervisiorBuild" = $view.Config.Product.Build
            "Make" = $view.Hardware.SystemInfo.Vendor
            "Model" = $view.Hardware.SystemInfo.Model
            "CPUSocketCount" = $view.Hardware.CPUInfo.numCPUPackages
            "CPUCoreCount" = $view.Hardware.CPUInfo.numCPUCores
            "LogicalCPUCount" = $view.Hardware.CPUInfo.numCPUThreads
            "CPYType" = $view.Hardware.CpuPkg.Discription
            "Memory" = [math]::Round([math]::Round($h.MemoryTotalGB, 2), 2)
            "Nics100MB" = $100mbNIC
            "Nics1GB" = $1GBNIC
            "Nics10GB" = $10GBNIC
            "NicsOther" = $otherNIC
            "DatacenterName" = $DataCenter
            "ClusterName" = $Cluster
        }`

`function Enter-CellData
{
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$WorkSheet,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [int]$CellRow,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [int]$CellColumn,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$Data
    )`

```
$WorkSheet.Cells.Item($CellRow, $CellColumn) = $Data
$script:Column++
```

`}`

Comment: Please show the code of `Enter-CellData` (at the very least the `Param()` definition and how you check that the `Data` parameter is empty) as well as the code initializing `$VMHostObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Ive figured it out in the enter-celldata function I have the wrong data types ive entered the correct ones now and it works

`param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [Object]$WorkSheet,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [int]$CellRow,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [int]$CellColumn,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [PsObject]$Data
    )`